# How to fetch similar type of JSON data using RestAssured

Tags: java, rest, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I have a GET Request where I have data for almost 30 users. I need to fetch only those user's data who's hair color is Black. Please help as I am beginner in Rest API automation using Java.

Data can be found here: https://dummyjson.com/users

Sample Response for 1st user:

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "firstName": "Terry",
            "lastName": "Medhurst",
            "maidenName": "Smitham",
            "age": 50,
            "gender": "male",
            "email": "atuny0@sohu.com",
            "phone": "+63 791 675 8914",
            "username": "atuny0",
            "password": "9uQFF1Lh",
            "birthDate": "2000-12-25",
            "image": "https://robohash.org/hicveldicta.png",
            "bloodGroup": "A−",
            "height": 189,
            "weight": 75.4,
            "eyeColor": "Green",
            "hair": {
                "color": "Black",
                "type": "Strands"
            },
            "domain": "slashdot.org",
            "ip": "117.29.86.254",
            "address": {
                "address": "1745 T Street Southeast",
                "city": "Washington",
                "coordinates": {
                    "lat": 38.867033,
                    "lng": -76.979235
                },
                "postalCode": "20020",
                "state": "DC"
            },
            "macAddress": "13:69:BA:56:A3:74",
            "university": "Capitol University",
            "bank": {
                "cardExpire": "06/22",
                "cardNumber": "50380955204220685",
                "cardType": "maestro",
                "currency": "Peso",
                "iban": "NO17 0695 2754 967"
            },
            "company": {
                "address": {
                    "address": "629 Debbie Drive",
                    "city": "Nashville",
                    "coordinates": {
                        "lat": 36.208114,
                        "lng": -86.58621199999999
                    },
                    "postalCode": "37076",
                    "state": "TN"
                },
                "department": "Marketing",
                "name": "Blanda-O'Keefe",
                "title": "Help Desk Operator"
            },
            "ein": "20-9487066",
            "ssn": "661-64-2976",
            "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/534.24 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/12.0.702.0 Safari/534.24"
        },
```

Comment: As per their docs, they provide an endpoint to filter users:
https://dummyjson.com/docs/users#filter

Comment: What data of `Black` hair users do you want to get? if you want whole user object, then see the docs @MuhammadOvi mentioned.

Comment: @Muhammad Ovi: I guess it was just added few hours ago since previously it was not there. Thanks anyways :)